# How to add a cell in html table and check for duplicates, without entering the following loop?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hey guys I am trying to add a new cell in html table and while checking for duplicates in the table. I loop over the table to check for duplicates but I want this alert to only show if there is a duplicate or not? Right now the alert is looping with the **each** function? It's probably an easy task but I can't handle it. Can someone help me?

```js
$("#btnCheck").on("click", function() {
  let company_name = $("#test1").val();

  $('#companyTable tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() === company_name) {
        alert("duplicate  found");
        return false;
      } else {
        alert("duplicate NOT found");
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="companyTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Company Name</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>toyota</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bmw</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>suzuki</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="text" id="test1" />
<input type="button" id="btnCheck" value="ADD" />
```

Comment: Remove the `else` condition...? Also note that `return false` can be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not common to *JQuery*, but in casual JavaScript this should work :

```
    document.querySelector("#btnCheck").onclick = () => {
        const companyName = document.querySelector("#test1").value;
        let found = false;
        document.querySelectorAll("#companyTable td").forEach(cell => {
            if(cell.innerText == companyName){
                 found = true
            }
        })
        alert("duplicate "+(found ? "" : "NOT ")+" found");
    }
```

- You do not need to query rows then cells.
- alerting at each cell isn't the right thing to do. You should (as above) store your result (=`found`), and at the end of the loop only use your result.

---

*Note*: Using `forEach` in this case doesn't seem the most efficient way. You should rather you a casual `for` loop in order to `break` it as soon as you find a match :

```
const cells = document.querySelectorAll("#companyTable td");
found = false;
for(let i = 0; i < cells.length; i++){
    if(cells[i].innerText == companyName) {
        found = true;
        break; // Stop the loop
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly for me. I was writing it in jQuery because of the project I am making, however it is not an obligation

Answer (score 1):

Break early from the outer loop, and only alert if it's not found after the loop:

```
$("#btnCheck").on("click", function () {

  let company_name = $("#test1").val();
  let found = false;
  $('#companyTable tr').each(function () {
    $(this).find('td').each(function() {
      if ($(this).text() === company_name) {
        alert("duplicate  found");
        found = true;
        return false;
      }
    });
    if (found) {
       // no need to search through other rows either
       return false;
    }

  });
  if (!found) {
    alert("duplicate NOT found");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In JQuery I would use something like

```
$("#companyTable tr td:contains('"+textToSearch+"')")
```

This should return all TD objects inside TR rows of your TABLE id="companyTable" which contains "textToSearch"